# TypeError: JQuery(...).downCount is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have been banging my head against this for a bit. The countdown timer I am using has not been hooking in correctly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/downCount.js"></script>

wp_enqueue_script('downCount', WL_TEMPLATE_DIR_URI .'/js/downCount.js');
```

Those are the two ways I have tried to link my .js.

```
<script class="source" type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('.countdown').downCount({
            date: '09/09/2016 12:00:00',
            offset: +10
            });
</script>
```

There is my hook. I used to have it like this.

```
  <script class="source" type="text/javascript">
            $('.countdown').downCount({
                date: '09/09/2016 12:00:00',
                offset: +10
                });
    </script>
```

When I have it loaded like that I get almost the same error so in the browser I change it to jQuery instead of the $. When I do that it works perfectly, but when I load the page with that fix already in place I get the error in my title.

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script('jauery.downCount'` is it a typo? if not make it jquery

Comment: `<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>` does `bloginfo` do an actual echo/print? If not that line will not output anything

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That definitely was a typo. Did not fix anything though.

Comment: bloginfo is a wordpress function that gets and prints what is within the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd add a jquery [dependency](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/), then add a .js file that depends on the `downCount` where I'd put all my `downCount` related script

```
wp_enqueue_script('downCount', WL_TEMPLATE_DIR_URI .'/js/downCount.js', array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script('downCount_script', WL_TEMPLATE_DIR_URI .'/js/my_countdown.js', array('downCount'));
```

And in my `my_countdown.js` I'd add

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    "use strict";

    $('.countdown').downCount({
        date: '09/09/2016 12:00:00',
        offset: +10
    });
});
```

Should be working.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad I could help :)